# April fool's annoying browser cache refuses to flush

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, redirect, flush

I've spent my weekend programming a little April Fool's joke, but it doesn't work just the way I want it to yet.

I have a Drupal 6 based website on which I want to change as little as possible. The idea is that all images that are served from the /files directory are redirected to an external webserver (myserver) that flips the image upside down and then serves it to the browser.

To make the Drupal website (targetserver) redirect all requests for images to the other server, I set up a .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^aprilFool$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://myserver/aprilFool/?url=http://targetserver/files/$1 [R=302,L]
```

And so far it works great! When I enable everything, the April Fool's trickery changes some of the images and they get displayed in the client's browser.

But when I disable the .htaccess @targetserver, my browser refuses to realize it was only meant to be a temporary joke and forget the edited images  :(

Here is a sniplet of the Perl script on myserver/aprilFool:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
# Identify ourselves through the useragent, to prevent endless redirect loops
$ua->agent( 'aprilFool' );

# Load remote file
my $response = $ua->get( $url );
if ( $response->is_error ) { die "Cannot retrieve document $url\n"; }
my $imageData = $response->content;


# Determine the file's mime type, need that to determine if we want to change it or not
my $ft = File::Type->new();
my $format = $ft->mime_type( $imageData );

# If the file is an image, flip it
if ( $format =~ m/^image\// ) {
        my $image=Image::Magick->new;
        $image->BlobToImage( $imageData );
        $image->Flip();
        $imageData = $image->ImageToBlob();
}

# Send HTTP headers
print "Content-type:$format\r\n";
print "\r\n";
print $imageData;
```

I've tried the following without success:

1. Add an extra header in the script: print "Cache-Control:
   max-age=36\r\n";
2. Add a line in .htaccess @targetserver: Header set Expires "Mon Mar 12 15:45:00 CET
   2012"
3. Change the name for image.jpg in various ways tmp-image.jpg,
   image.jpg.tmp by changing the RewriteRule in .htaccess @myserver

But after disabling the .htaccess the targetserver keeps sending 304 => 'Not Modified' until I manually flush the browser cache.

So my question is: How can I make April 1st last only one day, preferably until midnight ... How can I make the browser realize it has to reload the original image once the joke is over?

Comment: Dont' you mean `Mon Mar 12 2012 15:45:00 CET`.  see http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-58 for a  discussion of defaults.  They aren't what you might expect :-)

Comment: Tried the Expire header with the correct time format, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: On the other hand, I found about:cache?device=disk in Firefox, which basically displays all files in cache and their expiry date/time. This proved that the Cache-Control header *is* working. For Firefox to expire the image, it is required that I use a new/clean tab.

Comment: Even if you don't specify an Expire then most browsers will assume a default cache period which is 10% of the age (now - Last-modified).  The safest thing to do is to force no caching.

Comment: True, but default expiry period is something like half a year or so. Can't remember for sure, but it is way too long for a little joke like this. Thanks for your help TerryE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a browser issue. Closing the tab, reopening a new one flushed the old images.

Answer (score 2):

This is a funny question :-)

Just disable the redirect when it isn't april first. 302's are not cached by the browser.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} ^1$
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} ^3$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^aprilFool$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://myserver/aprilFool/?url=http://targetserver/files/$1 [R=302,L]
```

You'll have to check if the values 1 and 3 are correct to match april first, but I think TIME_MON is 0-11 and TIME_DAY is 1-31

Comment: The idea was to manually change the .htaccess file, but this is a brilliant little addition that makes my life even easier! I have a few days left to experiment with this :o) Thnx!

Comment: Created a small perl script and accompanying .htacces to check the TIME_MON, but it appears you are wrong about the month. This is the output I got couple of minutes ago (Wed Mar 14 11:23:02 CET 2012):

TIME: 20120314112302
TIME_DAY: 14
TIME_HOUR: 11
TIME_MIN: 23
TIME_MON: 03
TIME_SEC: 02
TIME_WDAY: 3
TIME_YEAR: 2012

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing your results. So change `^3$` to `^04$` and `^1$` to I think `^01$` or, since I'm not sure about the leading zero, `^0?1$`.

Comment: I would definitely been bitten by the leading zero if you hadn't mentioned it :) Have to do nightly check one of these days if all works. Basically this is the trick I did to figure it out: RewriteRule (.*) apacheServerVariables/?TIME_DAY=%{TIME_DAY}&TIME_MON=%{TIME_MON} ... Combined with a little script that spits out the URI. So I'm pretty sure about the leading 0

Comment: The apache docs seem to be missing any relevant info about these variables. The only thing I could find is in french and doesn't mention the leading zero; http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/expr.html :'-(